# Can I use the reduced mass principle in a spring-damper system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mass, friction, spring

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/orbv.html#rm

I want to know, if I can use the reduced mass principle to solve a two object spring-damper system.

In the books and webpages that I have check out, this principle is used only with simple spring systems; without any damping.

I know that this principle is a consequence of the 3th Newton's Law. I just want to be sure if this principle can be also be used when the objects are connected using a spring and a damper?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE ! The reduced mass is a technique, not a principle. You should show some effort and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It works just fine with a spring rather than a damper. The reduced mass technique just gives the relation between force and acceleration, so it will work regardless of what the source of the force is, as long as the force is between the two objects.

Comment: Yes, indeed you are correct. This is also supported by several papers I found.